# Log viewer in Glassfish 2 throws Exception

Tags: java, ubuntu, glassfish

When I click certain records in the log viewer of a Glassfish 2 server running on 64-bit Ubuntu the error report opens a new popup but instead of the actual error I get a server exception:

## HTTP Status 500 -

---

**type** Exception report

**message**

**description**The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

**exception**

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Expression '$property{list}' did not resolve to a List! Found: 'java.lang.String'
```

**root cause**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expression '$property{list}' did not resolve to a List! Found: 'java.lang.String'
```

**note** The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the Sun Java System Application Server 9.1_01 logs.

---

#### Sun Java System Application Server 9.1_01

The stack trace in the server log is:

```
[#|2011-07-15T11:58:52.561+0000|INFO|sun-appserver9.1|com.sun.jsftemplating|_ThreadID=35;_ThreadName=httpWorkerThread-4848-1;|JSFT0003: VariableResolver was unable to find key (logEntryDetail) in ResourceBundle (help).|#]

[#|2011-07-15T11:58:52.586+0000|WARNING|sun-appserver9.1|javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle|_ThreadID=35;_ThreadName=httpWorkerThread-4848-1;_RequestID=aa6c0f08-ce0f-4a10-bdc5-b835658db2bc;|executePhase(RENDER_RESPONSE 6,com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl@955e041) threw exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expression '$property{list}' did not resolve to a List! Found: 'java.lang.String'
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutForEach.getList(LayoutForEach.java:119)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutForEach.encode(LayoutForEach.java:168)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.encode(LayoutElementBase.java:271)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutDefinition.encode(LayoutDefinition.java:232)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.renderer.TemplateRenderer.encodeEnd(TemplateRenderer.java:139)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:836)
    at com.sun.webui.jsf.util.RenderingUtilities.renderComponent(RenderingUtilities.java:99)
    at com.sun.webui.jsf.renderkit.html.PropertyRenderer.renderPropertyComponents(PropertyRenderer.java:200)
    at com.sun.webui.jsf.renderkit.html.PropertyRenderer.encodeEnd(PropertyRenderer.java:161)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:836)
    at com.sun.webui.jsf.util.RenderingUtilities.renderComponent(RenderingUtilities.java:99)
    at com.sun.webui.jsf.renderkit.html.PropertySheetSectionRenderer.renderProperties(PropertySheetSectionRenderer.java:192)
    at com.sun.webui.jsf.renderkit.html.PropertySheetSectionRenderer.renderPropertySheetSection(PropertySheetSectionRenderer.java:152)
    at com.sun.webui.jsf.renderkit.html.PropertySheetSectionRenderer.encodeEnd(PropertySheetSectionRenderer.java:95)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:836)
    at com.sun.webui.jsf.util.RenderingUtilities.renderComponent(RenderingUtilities.java:99)
    at com.sun.webui.jsf.renderkit.html.PropertySheetRenderer.renderPropertySheetSections(PropertySheetRenderer.java:172)
    at com.sun.webui.jsf.renderkit.html.PropertySheetRenderer.encodeEnd(PropertySheetRenderer.java:122)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:836)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.encodeChild(LayoutElementBase.java:480)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.encodeChild(LayoutElementBase.java:477)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.encodeChild(LayoutElementBase.java:477)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.encodeChild(LayoutElementBase.java:477)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.encodeChild(LayoutElementBase.java:477)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutComponent.encode(LayoutComponent.java:226)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.encode(LayoutElementBase.java:271)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutDefinition.encode(LayoutDefinition.java:225)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.renderView(LayoutViewHandler.java:484)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:106)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:251)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:144)
    at com.sun.faces.extensions.avatar.lifecycle.PartialTraversalLifecycle.render(PartialTraversalLifecycle.java:92)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:245)
    at com.sun.enterprise.tools.admingui.servlet.DelayedInitFacesServlet.service(DelayedInitFacesServlet.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.servletService(ApplicationFilterChain.java:411)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:317)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:198)
    at com.sun.webui.jsf.util.UploadFilter.doFilter(UploadFilter.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:577)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:577)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1080)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:577)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1080)
    at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:272)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(DefaultProcessorTask.java:637)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.doProcess(DefaultProcessorTask.java:568)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.process(DefaultProcessorTask.java:813)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.executeProcessorTask(DefaultReadTask.java:341)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:263)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:214)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:265)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.WorkerThreadImpl.run(WorkerThreadImpl.java:116)|#]
```

Google came up with these two questions but with no real solution:
1. http://www.java.net/node/703568
2. http://www.java.net/node/682666

Does anybody have the same error or know the solution?